# I have a desktop not a laptop, so why is Windows 10 (after update KB5005565) telling me my battery is low?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Windows 10 after update KB5005565 is displaying a message that my battery is low.  I have a desktop not a laptop. Can I ignore this error or does Windows take some action, such as changing how it uses the CPU or GPU, if it thinks battery is low?

Comment: Do you use a UPS? A UPS may cause Windows to think it has a battery.

Comment: I have a Desktop and a UPS and there are no notifications about battery. Look in Settings, Battery and disable any notifications. Look at Power and Sleep settings as well.